# Explain this makefile recipe construction

Tags: makefile

```
install_target: first FORCE
    if not exist C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\Sources\qtbase\bin\ \
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\static\?\?C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\static\?\lib \ 
mkdir C:$(INSTALL_ROOT)\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\Sources\qtbase\bin\? \
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\static\?\?C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\static\?\lib & \
if not exist C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\Sources\qtbase\bin\? \
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\static\?\?C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\static\?\lib exit 1
```

What does question mark mean?

Comment: Why here appeared question marks? I tried to build static qt libraries with mingw32-make. after mingw32-make I get these Makefile

Comment: This looks like a Windows command-line interface question, not a makefile question.